# Is the subspace of $L^2([0,1])$ of all "functions" vanishing on $[0,1/2]$ closed?

Tags: lebesgue-integral, lp-spaces

I am trying to understand the following example from my lecture notes:

> $\mathcal{H} := L^2([0,1],\lambda)$,
>   then 
>   $$K := \{f \in \mathcal{H} \colon f(x) = 0, \text{ for } 0 \leq x \leq \frac{1}{2} \;\lambda\text{-almost everywhere}\}$$
>   is a closed subspace.

The subspace properties follow from Minkowski's inequality, i.e. for $[f],[g] \in K$
$$ \left(\int_{[0,\frac{1}{2}]} |f + g|^2 \right)^{1/2}
= \| (f+g)\cdot \chi_{[0,\frac{1}{2}]} \|_2
\leq \| f \cdot \chi_{[0,\frac{1}{2}]} \|_2 + \| g \cdot \chi_{[0,\frac{1}{2}]} \|_2
= 0
$$

**Is this correct?**

I'm not able to show closedness: Consider a sequence $([f_n])_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ in $K$ converging to some $[f] \in \mathcal{H}$. The problem is that convergence w.r.t. the Norm in L2 only gives my a subsequence $(f_{n_k})$ (note that I dropped the equivalence classes) converging pointwise almost everywhere. So I'm guessing the proof can't be done using the dominated convergence theorem.

**How would you prove closedness?**

Comment: Just as a sideremark: You don't to be this rigorous with equivalence classes when talkin about measure equivalence. In literature (expect when introducing this concept for the first time) one omitts the classes and works directly with the representative which is slightly abusive but much more confortable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. Assume not. Then $f_n\to f$ in $L^2$ but $f\neq 0$ on a set $E\subset [0,1/2]$ of positive measure. Then $\|f-f_n\|_{L^2(E)}=\|f\|_{L^2(E)}= C, \forall n$, which contradicts the fact that $f_n\to f$.

Edit: to be precise, the contradiction follows from what I said together with the fact that $\|\cdot\|_{L^2([0,1/2])}\geq\|\cdot\|_{L^2(E)}$.

Comment: Thanks! In fact, even $\|\cdot\|_{L^2([0,1])}\geq\|\cdot\|_{L^2(E)}$ should hold and give the contradiction?

Comment: Yes. Indeed, $\|f-f_n\|_{L^2([0,1])}$ is precisely what you need to check. I don't know why I wrote $[0,1/2]$ in my edit.